# How do I get a string value from service in an Angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-services, angular2-databinding

I am trying to get the value of a string variable explanationText from my QuizService to display in my di-quiz component template using data-binding. console.log is showing undefined for explanationText and data-binding to the template isn't displaying anything for explanationText when an answer is selected. Please see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app

Any idea why this is not working? Please can you help. Thank you!

In my **quiz.service.ts** file, I have:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}) {
  export class QuizService {
  explanationText: string;
  ...

  setExplanationAndCorrectAnswerMessages() {
    this.question = this.getQuestion;
    if (this.question) {
      if (this.correctAnswers.length === 1) {
        this.explanation = ' is correct because ' + this.question.explanation + '.';
      }
      if (this.correctAnswers.length > 1) {
        this.explanation = ' are correct because ' + this.question.explanation + '.';
      }
    }

    if (this.correctAnswers && this.correctAnswers.length === 1) {
      const correctAnswersText = this.correctAnswers[0];
      this.explanationText = 'Option ' + correctAnswersText + this.explanation;
      console.log(this.explanationText);
      this.correctAnswerMessage = 'The correct answer is Option ' + this.correctAnswers[0] + '.';
      console.log(this.correctAnswerMessage);
    }
    if (this.correctAnswers && this.correctAnswers.length > 1) {
      if (this.correctAnswers[0] && this.correctAnswers[1]) {
        const correctAnswersText = this.correctAnswers[0] + ' and ' + this.correctAnswers[1];
        this.explanationText = 'Options ' + correctAnswersText + this.explanation;
        console.log(this.explanationText);
        this.correctAnswerMessage = 'The correct answers are Options ' + correctAnswersText + '.';
        console.log(this.correctAnswerMessage);
      }
      ...
    }
  }
```

In my **di-quiz.component.ts**, I have a getter/setter and constructor as follows:

```
get explanation(): string { return this.quizService.explanationText; };
@Input() set explanation(value: string) { this.explanationText = value; };

constructor(private quizService: QuizService,
            private timerService: TimerService,
            private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.explanationText = this.explanation;
  console.log("ExpTxt: " + this.explanationText);
}
```

and in my **di-quiz.component.html**, I have

```
<section id="question" [class.answered]="answer">
  <span *ngIf="!answer">{{ question?.questionText }}</span>
  <span *ngIf="answer">{{ explanationText }}</span>
</section>
```

Comment: first try to initialize the explanationText in your service

Comment: In the code above `explanationText` is uninitialized. How are you initializing it in `QuizService`?

Comment: I am setting the explanationText in the setExplanationAndCorrectAnswerMessages() function (see above).

Comment: I have tried the following code but still not able to get it to work: @Input() set explanationTextVal(value) { this.explanationText = value; };

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.explanationTextVal && changes.explanationTextVal.currentValue !== changes.explanationTextVal.firstChange) {
      this.explanationText = changes.explanationTextVal.currentValue;
    }
  }

Comment: @multiv123 You have posted an enormous stackblitz that is extremely hard to follow. There is so much wrong with the design that a simple answer here is not going to solve your problem - you need to redesign the whole project. Did you base your project on this https://github.com/marvinrusinek/codelab-quiz?

Comment: Yes this is my project.

Comment: @multiv123 Can you provide more focus to your question. Can you recreate the problem you're having with a very simple stackblitz that demonstrates the specific problem you're having?

Comment: @Input() set explanation(value: string) { this.explanationText = value; }; why this?

Comment: I simplified it somewhat, please see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ms9xaw. Still working on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I check your stackblitz code and found the issue. Its because you are registering your QuizService in DependencyInjectionQuizComponent and QuestionComponent, which creates multiple instace.

So when question component fires **setExplanationAndCorrectAnswerMessages** it update explanationText in different instance but your DIQuizComponent expect from different instance.

To fix this you have to remove QuizService from QuestionComponent providers.

I have forked and updated the code. Here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app-rextrq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fquestion%2Fquestion.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think it was so simple. I'm looking at the code. I'll need to make similar change for correctAnswerMessage.

Comment: It seems that it only shows the explanationText if the answer is correct, otherwise the question box is empty.

Comment: You need to check logic or conditions how you are displaying it. I didn't check.

Answer (score 2):

Change above constructor like this,

```
constructor(
  private quizService: QuizService,
  private timerService: TimerService,
  private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
     this.explanation = 'Text you want';
     this.explanationText = this.explanation;
     console.log("ExpTxt: " + this.quizService.explanationText);
}
```

Comment: I need the value of explanationText determined by the setExplanation function in my service.